# Node.js Express mongoose query find

Tags: debugging, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a little problem with Express and mongoose using Node.js . I pasted the code in pastebin, for a better visibility.

Here is the app.js: http://pastebin.com/FRAFzvjR
Here is the routes/index.js: http://pastebin.com/gDgBXSy6

Since the db.js isn't big, I post it here:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = function () {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',
    function(err) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
    }
  );
};

var User = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, index: { unique: true }},
    mdp: String    
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

As you can see, I used the console.log to debug my app, and I found that, in routes/index.js, only the a appeared. That's weird, it's as if the script stopped  (or continue without any response) when

```
userModel.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, data)
```

is tried.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never connect to your database. Your connect method is within the db.export, but that is never called as a function from your app.

Also, you are overwriting your module.exports - if you want multiple functions/classes to be exported, you must add them as different properties of the module.export object. ie.:

```
module.export.truthy = function() { return true; }
module.export.falsy = function() { return false; }
```

When you then `require` that module, you must call the function (`trueFalse.truthy();`) in order to get the value. Since you never execute the function to connect to your database, you are not recieveing any data.

Comment: Thank you, what you said helped me a lot. Look at my comment on the other message if you want to know the details. :D

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things real quick.

1. Make sure you're on the latest mongoose (2.5.3). Update your package.json and run npm update.
2. Try doing a `console.log(augments)` before your `if (err)`. It's possible that an error is happening.
3. Are you sure you're really connecting to the database? Try explicitly connecting at the top of your file (just for testing) `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');`

I'll update if I get any other ideas.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. I think I wasn't really connected. I thought that module.exports alone automatically does the function. But I was wrong. Is module.exports equivalent to exports?

Comment: yeah module.exports is the same as exports